# Javascript confirm ain't working as it should

Tags: javascript, confirm

I have this `js` function that checks if `OK` or `Cancel` is pressed and returns false or true. What I am trying to do is that when is true to run the remaining `js` function in the order they appear but it isn't working; `deleteList('$row->listID');updateList();` are never executed.

**Javascript:**

```
function deleteConfirm(){
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wanna delete that list?")){
            return true;
    }
    else{
            return false;
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="listID" onclick="return deleteConfirm();deleteList('$row->listID');updateList();">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're returning on the first statement (so the others never run), instead only hop out on a cancel, like this:

```
onclick="if(deleteConfirm()) { deleteList('$row->listID'); updateList(); }"
```

You can also greatly simplify your function, like this:

```
function deleteConfirm(){
  return confirm("Are you sure you wanna delete that list?");
}
```

...or if possible go the unobtrusive route, using `data-` attributes to get the `listID`.

Comment: "if possible go the unobtrusive route, using data- attributes to get the listID" can you please explain what you mean by that?